# Simple Java Interface Implementation

Tags: java, interface

Will you help me to solve this code?

```
interface Speaker {

    void speak();

}
public class Politician implements Speaker {

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Politician speaking");
    }
}
public class Lecturer implements Speaker {

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Lecturer spaeking");
    }

}

public class SpeakerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         //??????????????? how to execute?


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: The question here is obvious: How to "instanciate" and use the interface :) Upvoting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Speaker s1,s2;
s1 = new Lecturer();
s2 = new Politician();

s1.speak(); // it print  'Lecturer spaeking'
s2.speak(); // it print  'Politician speaking'

}
```

Comment: Thanks all of your quick reply!
I found my answer.
But I have to initialize every class. I thought there will be a single line code that will execute all the method at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Speaker s = new AnInstanceOfAClassThatImplementsSpeaker();//instead of //??????????????? how to execute?
s.speak(); // will call appropriate speak() method`
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is basically a contract which methods are visible to other classes.  In contrary to abstract classes, no functionality is inside (except for static methods).

The concrete implementation of the methods of the interface is done in the class(es) which implements the interface. So the classes must keep to the method contract of the interface.

So you declare a variable of type `Speaker` in your main method and assign an instance of the class (`Politician` or `Lecturer` in this example).

```
public class SpeakerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Speaker is the Interface. We know it has a speak() method and do not care about the implementation (i.e. if its a politicial or a lecturer speaking)
         Speaker firstSpeaker = new Politician();
         firstSpeaker.speak();
         Speaker secondSpeaker = new Lecturer();
         secondSpeaker.speak();

    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my another question. If there lots of implemented class like that, I have to initiate every class. is there any way to make it a single line code? is that possible? any other algorithm? Thanks in advance.